# How to resolve which function is called based on the type of objects in a container?

Tags: c++, inheritance, containers

I have some basic inheritance trees:

```
class Base {
    virtual double func() = 0;
    // functionality is not important for the problem
    // but it's good to know that Base has some virtual functions
};
class DerivedA : public Base {
    virtual double func() {}; // implementation A
};
class DerivedB : public Base {
    virtual double func() {}; // implementation B
};
```

I have a container holding a pointer to either `DerivedA` or `DerivedB` instances.

```
void f1(std::vector<Base*> a) () { /* some code */ }

int main(in, char**) {
  std::vector<Base*> base_container;
  f1(base_container); // works fine
}
```

Almost everything works on Base, but I have some function, not specified in `DerivedA` or `DerivedB`, that is implementation specific, but works on a `DerivedA` or `DerivedB` container. Let's assume the following code snippet:

```
void f2(std::vector<DerivedA*> a) () { /* implementation A specific code */ }
void f2(std::vector<DerivedB*> a) () { /* implementation B specific code */ }
```

What is the best practise to call the correct function? I list some possible solutions, which came to my mind, but they all have major drawbacks.

1. I could hold all data in implementation specific containers. However, `f1()` won't work anymore since `std::vector<DerivedA*>` is not a child of `std::vector<Base*>` (for good reasons!).
2. I could manually cast all objects all the time, but that is ugly.
3. I could manually call the correct function that expects a Base container by giving them distinctive name (like `f2_a` and `f2_b`), but that seems ugly.
4. I could implement f2 as a function template specialization, but that seems abusive.
5. I could try to make the function on the container depend only on functions of the objects in the container and then implement overloaded functions for them. This is a good solution in several cases, but in my case it really is a function on the container, giving different implementations on the container for `DerivedA` and `DerivedB`, not just iterating over the contents of the container.

How would you implement such thing? How can I get a Container that is able to be passed to both `f1()` and `f2()`?

Comment: What would `f2()` do for a container that contained two objects, one a `DerivedA` and the other a `DerivedB`?

Comment: Could you provide an example why this could be useful? I can't see it. From an OO point of view, this seems to be messy. This might be the reason why your approaches turn out to be ugly as well?

Comment: You might be right. I'm in the machine learning niché. So my base is a predictive model, whereas the derived classes are regression or classification models. I now want to calculate measurements of accuracy of the models and they differ from classification and regression.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson it would actually calculate something, making no sense in the context. Would still work from a technical point of view.

Comment: Again - it would be totally fine to have all in `std::vector<DerivedA*>` containers, but then, how do I define functions, where I can pass both `std::vector<DerivedA*>` and `std::vector<DerivedB*>` ?

Comment: @hildensia that sounds like a good idea. Expecting `std::vector<Base*>` to support different operations depending on the dynamic type of the contained objects sounds like a violation of the Liskov substitution principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to have your inheritance represent substitution and have the base class have a fully-formed interface that does all the work, using virtual methods to pick which derived class methods to use. Then `f2` just takes a vector of base pointers.

Otherwise, if there really are specifically different interfaces in the derived classes that you need to access (and if there are, take one moment to think about what you did with your design), your best appoach is differently named methods, one for each derived type, each of which accepts a vector of base pointers. With appropriately named methods it will be clear to the user which type is expected.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility could be making a [visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).  The functionality based on the derived type will be in the overloaded visit() method of the visitor instead of the overloaded function working on the complete container.  This works also on containers containing both derived classes.

The drawback is some added complexity and dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make sense.

You can't call a function on a vector of derived types when the source container could contain either type.

You will either need to split these up into two vectors, either by using dynamic cast or by checking some kind of `type()` virtual function. Only then will you be able to call these functions with confidence.

The ideal and cleanest option is your option number 5, it is the way dynamic runtime polymorphism is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would not use raw pointers. `shared_ptr` or a `ptr_...<>` container from Boost to name a few alternatives.
2. I would not expose the kind of container used, or the fact that objects are stored in a container for that matter. Separate container walking from actions on individual objects.
3. I would implement the select-function-based-on-object-type pattern with a virtual function, because that's what virtual functions are for.

Now back from the ideal world to our unfortunate planet.

If you have an `std::vector<Derived*>` at hand, you just call the correct statically resolved function for `std::vector<Derived*>`, overloaded or distinctly named, your choice.

If all you have is `std::vector<Base*>` and you guess that all of the pointers stored in there actually point to `Derived1*`, you probably want to verify your guess somehow (what if in fact you have a mix of `Derived1*`, `Derived2*` and who knows, maybe some kind of `Derived3*` that was added by your colleague while you were not looking?) How do you do that? Once you use `dynamic_cast<>` for checking, you may just as well use `dynamic_cast<>` for the rest of everything.

If all you have is `std::vector<Base*>` and you know a priori that all of the pointers stored in there actually point to `Derived1*`, they are probably stored in an `std::vector<Base*>` for no good reason (since much needed type information is lost and has to be recreated in ugly ways) and you should consider changing it to `std::vector<Derived1*>`.

Answer (score 0):

you should used dynamic_cast
which return null with the bad conversion
and use

```
if(dynamic_cast<DerivedA>(ptr)!=null) {...}
else if(dynamic_cast<DerivedB>(ptr)!=null) {...}
```

Comment: This translates to my solution no. 3, right? Manually resolving to the right function.

Comment: if you have one container that you loop through, then use dynamic_casting, you can call the right function, however the function parameter shouldn't be a container, it should be a pointer to the specific class

Comment: No, I think it's your solution no. 2. This answer is suggesting to do the cast inside `f1()`.

Answer (score 0):

Templates (or a mixture of templates and overloading) offers one possible solution, although they might tend to become unwieldy here.

```
template <class T>
void f1(std::vector<T*> a)
{
    // code that doesn't care whether T is Base or DerivedA or DerivedB
}

void f2(std::vector<DerivedA*> a)
{
    // code that requires T = DerivedA
}
void f2(std::vector<DerivedB*> a)
{
    // code that requires T = DerivedB
}
```

Attempting to pass a `std::vector<Base*>` to `f2()` would result in a compile error.